# MYSQL Cluster (NDB) vs Galera for replication

Tags: php, mysql

1. what is difference between Galera and NDB.
2. who is the best replication for maria DB or MYSQL.
3. what is the advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 2):

1: Galera replication with mysql or mariadb simply duplicates your entire database onto multiple servers. Each server is identical and can be used for read and write. Galera can be used with WAN replication, and is less sensitive to network latency. NDB can be used for scale-out with partitioning, whereas galera mysql or mariadb will require manual sharding.

2: MariaDB and MySQL are similar products. It depends on your requirements, although if you want to use Galera in particular I would suggest MariaDB because it is supported by the MariaDB foundation, whereas Oracle is pushing MySQL Cluster and has nothing to do with Galera.

3: No idea what you are asking.